# Informatica folders mapping

Tags: informatica

I have a question about informatica powercenter designer folders and mappings. I have a folder in my workplace which is created by admin but i am the owner for it, anyone can open the folder to see my mappings if they know my employee number and copy my mappings to their folders and they can read/copy my work. I am searching for an option if I can hide some of the mappings not from admin but only from some of the people or people who have same access privileges as me. Any help is appreciated, because i only want to make invisible certain mappings not the whole folder.

Comment: Other either have read access to your folder or not. If they do, they can see all the content. If they will be revoked the read access, the entire folder will not be visible to them. Unfortunately you can't manage permissions per object.

Comment: Ask your administrator i think he/she can do it. Basically, he can remove other's RWX permission. But if someone has repository object read permission i think he should be able to see all your mappings. Another way is, always set all your mappings to check-out status . This will ensure that only you can see latest mapping(but this is not a very good idea).